# deserialize json to strongly typed object containing a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
public class Test 
{

   public Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   public static void main(String args[]){

       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       Test tt = new Test();
       tt.dict.Add("hello","divya");
       tt.dict.Add("bye", "divya");
       String s = serializer.Serialize(tt.dict); // s is {"hello":"divya","bye":"divya"}

       Test t = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(s,typeof(Test));
       Console.WriteLine(t.dict["hello"]); // gives error since dict is empty
   }
```

So the question is how do I deserialize a json string like {"hello":"divya","bye":"divya"} into a strongly typed object containing a dictionary.

Comment: You are serializing the dictionary and deserialize into your `Test` type. That doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize that into a `Dictionary`, the JSON would have to look a little different. It would have to define the `Test` class (loosely):

```
{
    dict: {
        "hello": "divya",
        "bye": "divya"
    }
}
```

See, the `dict` definition exists in the JSON. However, what you have there could be deserialized *directly* into the `Dictionary` like this:

```
tt.dict = (Dictionary<string, string>)serializer.Deserialize(s,
    typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
```